# Traveling wave solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Currently I am trying to introduce myself to traveling wave solutions and wave fronts. I came across different definitions. Sometimes traveling wave solutions are expressed as $u(x, t) = U(z)$, where $z = x − ct$ but sometimes $z=x+ct$. What's the difference?

Comment: Try plotting some snapshots of $ \sin(x + t) $ and $ \sin(x - t) $ and see what you learn.

Answer (score 2):

Functions of the form $u(x,t)=U(x-ct)$ are interpreted as "traveling to the right," while functions of the latter form travel to the left. Use Wolfram Alpha to plot a few such functions to see this effect.